# How waiting thread knows that shared resource is unlocked by another thread?

Tags: linux, multithreading, pthreads

I'm studying multi threaded application.
I'm using mutex for synchronization.

I want to understand how waiting thread come to know that the shared resource locked by another thread is unlocked now?

I need to understood the above in the case of "MUTEX" usage.

Comment: The short answer is that when a thread can't get a lock the OS puts it to sleep.  When the mutex is unlocked the OS wakes the waiting thread.  Exactly how this is done is implementation defined and complicated by different factors like scheduling policies.

Answer (score 0):

All threads in the process share a semaphore if it is globally defined.

Assume we have a writeLogMessage(char*) function that opens a file and writes the given String. Calling this method from multiple threads will cause unwanted (and unpredictable behaviour). Hence you could write a thread-safe wrapper function, that waits for other threads to free the shared resource (the logfile in this case).

```
sem_t log_mutex;

void writeLogTS(char *logmsg) 
{
  sem_wait(&log_mutex); //suspend the thread if another thread is currently writing to the log file
  writeLogMessage(logmsg);
  sem_wait(&log_mutex); //post the mutex semaphore
}
```

The function `sem_wait` will decrease the value of the semaphore if it is greater than 0. However, if the value of the `log_mutex` is 0, `sem_wait` will suspend the current threads execution until the value is increased again. Increasing the value is done by `sem_wait`.
I.e. the other threads know that the shared resource is available again, if the semaphore's value is greater than 0.

EDIT: To serve as a mutex, the semaphore log_mutex has to be initialised before the threads are started as follows: `sem_init(&log_mutex, 0, 1);` 
The second argument is 0 to guarantee that the semaphore is shared between threads and the third argument is the initial value. Cf. http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/sem_init.html

Comment: @Irohr Hello, I need to understood the same scenario in the case of "MUTEX" usage?

Comment: @BSalunke I am sorry if my writing was ambiguous. I added the initialisation of the semaphore. A mutex is a semaphore with an initial value of 1, hence allowing only one thread to enter a critical area (i.e. accessing a shared resource). A semaphore with an initial value greater than 1, say 4, allows 4 threads to access a resource simultaneously. This is used in Producer-Consumer scenarios as shown in the wikipedia article here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer%E2%80%93consumer_problem#Using_semaphores